# How to get ID from PHP table list

Tags: php, mysql

I created the following code to populate a table with data stored in database.
As you can see the data are also directly editable in the fields, what I am trying to do is to save the edited field(s) to the database.
If the field has been modified just overwrite the "old" field, if it has not been modified take the old field.

```
<?php

$querymod =" SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC ";

$result = mysql_query($querymod) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<div style='width: 100%; text-align: center;'>";                   
echo "<table style='margin: auto auto;'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Article Number</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$id    = $row['id'];
$img_name    = $row['img_name'];
$art_number    = $row['art_number'];
$description    = $row['description'];


echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<tr>
<td style='width: 20px;'><input name='id' id='id' value='".$id."' disabled='yes'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'></td>
<td style='width: 210px;'><img src='../../upload/content/uploads/". $img_name ."' width='200px'></td>
<td style='width: 100px;'><input type='text' name='art_number' value='".$art_number."'></td>
<td style='width: 100px;'><input type='text' name='description' value='".$description."'></td>
</tr>";     
}
echo "</table><br /><br /></div>";
echo "</form>";
```

?>

I know that with the "UPDATE" function I can update the database and the fields, but the problem is that I don't know how to get the ID of the modified row, and start the update of the related modified field.

Any hint please?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I have for example 10 different rows with obviously 10 different IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move:

```
echo "</form>";
```

inside the while-loop. You're starting a new form each time through the loop, but not closing it until the entire loop is done. This is creating incorrect nesting.

Also, get rid of `id='id'` (you probably don't need it) or do something to ensure that the IDs are unique.

Comment: Thank you man, I am such an idiot. :(
Now I have a problem with the style of the table. The first row is perfectly aligned, but the rest are a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

Use type=hidden for the input:

```
<td style='width: 20px;'><input name='id' id='id' value='".$id."' type='hidden'>
```

Comment: I tried with that, but the problem is that if I click on the "Save" button of the second row it get the ID always of the first row.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try getting rid of `id='id'` in the HTML. You can't have the same HTML ID on multiple elements, this could be confusing things.

Comment: I just saw the accepted answer. I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

`1`. Use a form per row

or:

`2`. Create one hidden input named `id`.  Use an `onClick='document.forms.form_name.id.value='$id';document.forms.form_name.submit();"` attribute for the submit button, but change type='submit' to type='button'. Append the $id value to the name of each of the other inputs.  Then, when the page reloads after submission, you will have the id and can also find the other inputs in POST:

```
echo "<form name='myform' action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
    <table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id          = $row['id'];
    $img_name    = $row['img_name'];
    $art_number  = $row['art_number'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $onClick = "document.forms.myform.id.value='$id';document.forms.myform.submit();";

    echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='button' name='save_$id' value='Save' onClick='$onClick'></td>
        <td><img src='../../upload/content/uploads/$img_name' width='200px'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='art_number_$id' value='$art_number'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='description_$id' value='$description'></td>
      </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n</form>\n";
```

Then, when save has been clicked, you can read the values in POST:

```
$id = !empty($_POST["id"]) ? $_POST["id"] : NULL;
$art_number = !empty($_POST["art_number_$id"]) ?$_POST["art_number_$id"] : NULL;
$description = !empty($_POST["description_$id"]) ?$_POST["description_$id"] : NULL;
```

which you can use to update the SQL database.